# takewhile in itertools takes one value too much

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-itertools

I have the following code to stop the iterator on a certain value, save the state until the value and return both the saved state and the original state. I am using takewhile from itertools to get the values till the given break_point, and then I use chain on the saved iterator until the break_point and the initial iterator to merge them:

```
from itertools import takewhile, chain

def iter_break(iterator_input, break_point):

    new_iter = list(takewhile(lambda x: x <= break_point-1, iterator_input))
    return chain(iter(new_iter), iterator_input)

import unittest


class TestEqual(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_iters(self):

        it = iter(range(20))
        old_it = iter_break(it, 10)
        self.assertEqual(list(it), list(old_it))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

The problem is, in the end the returned iterator and the full iterator I am returning are not similar since the returned one misses one value, and it misses the value that is equal to the break point itself. Please help.

Comment: either you try to remove "-1" from break_point-1 or you do "<" instead of "<="

Comment: how do you expect `takewhile` to stop iterating if it doesn't find an element that doesn't fit the condition? Of course the break point was consumed from the iterator, that is what stopped `takewhile`!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`it` is not just missing the breakpoint value, it's missing all the values before it because it's just an iterator created with `iter` and not a list, so `iter_sample` uses up values as it iterates over them with `takewhile`. This includes the breakpoint itself because `takewhile` needs to see that value in order to know that the condition is no longer satisfied.

Comment: @ivan_bilan `islice` is for taking a fixed number of elements regardless of the values but your question indicates that the iterator should stop before it reaches a certain value. Your test with `range` doesn't show a problem because every element has index equal to its value but this doesn't seem to be what you want. Try testing with more complicated lists. Also your problem was not the loss of a breakpoint but the fact that you were passing an iterator that could be consumed. Have you fixed that?

Comment: it should stop at a certain index, so islice does what is should. And yes, it also consumes the values, but using chain to merge the sliced iterator and the rest of the values that are left in the input iterator seems to work.